# Searching approach to evaluate domain specific expression

Tags: java, parsing, dsl

I'm working on a tool in the context of a java project to evaluate a custom domain specific, rule-like expression like

`min-5 avg datalist > Number`

with the individual tokens meaning the following:

- min-5 : optional minimum (or maximum, in that case max-5) occurences of the following term
- avg : an optional aggregation function which operates on the following token datalist (can also be sum or anything similar)
- datalist : A list of data (type: integer/ double) which will be available before the evaluation of the entire expression starts, can be reduced to a single value by the preceding aggregation function
- operator: conditional operator < or > or =
- Number: value for the conditional operator

Note(s):

> - The optional amount of occurrences and the aggregation can not happen both, that would make no sense.
> - There can be multiple of the above expressions, chained with and/or
> - These expressions are external input, not pre-defined

The evaluation of this expression should output a boolean

As I am rather new to expression evaluation / parsing I am searching for an elegant way to solve this, possibly with a java framework/tool.

What I've tried so far:

- Parsing by hand which turned out not so nicely
- Trying to use Janino Expression Evaluator, but I don't know how to handle this programmatically

I am searching for a solution to solve this in an elegant way, I am thankful for any suggestions

Comment: See my SO answer on how to build parsers (especially for expressions) easily.  These parsers have the nice property that you can use them to evaluate the expessions, too.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you try to do is a DSL (domain specific language) and the elegant way to solve your issue is to create a grammar for yuor specific language that help you on parsing function. 
Take a look at JavaCC or Antlr.

Comment: I looked into these and Antlr looks just fine for what I need. Thank you.